# Why can't Rewrite Cond find .php file inside folder?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite the URL with rewrite cond, but it doesn't seem to find the blog folder where article.php is located.. while the second code finds and includes the hash-tags perfectly.. What am I doing wrong here..

## Does not find public_html/blog/

```
#if on article page, get slugs and make into friendly url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog\article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2/? [L,R=302,NE]
```

## Does find public_html/blog/

```
#allow page direction to change the slugs into friendly seo URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule (?:^|/)blog/article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /article.php?article_uid=$1&article_title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/blog/article\.php\?article_uid=([^&]+)&article_title=([^&\ ]+)
```

With `/` and not `\` after `blog`